# How to use node-gdal with Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, gdal

I'm having some issues installing node-gdal (*npm install gdal*) with Electron. The current error I am receiving in the developer tab is:

```
Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register: '\\?\C:\Users\Tristan\Projects\electron-lir\node_modules\gdal\lib\binding\gdal.node'.
```

Can someone please help me to find a fix or a workaround, I'm using it for **translations between DXF and GeoJSON**.

Thanks so much.

Comment: As the author of `gdal-async` - the only currently maintained fork of the now abandoned `node-gdal`, I will gladly look into your issue if it doesn't work. You are free to open an issue on github.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. In fact, the problem started with the fact that I need to have Visual Studio installed in my system when installing `npm install -s gdal`